# How to set up eslint configuration for vue3 + vite 3 project?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, eslint, vite

In my vue3+vite3 project, I set up eslint, but notice the speed is a bit slow on the intelligence. Sometimes I have seen error messages that show duplicate error message coming from eslint and `ts`. I wonder if I have a messed up eslint config file. This is what I have

Can anyone let me know if I have anything I shouldn't here, or if there is any overkill things or redundant things. I'm pretty lost at this configuration. Just looking for something good for most people usage.

```
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es2021": true,
        "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
        "plugin:vue/base",
        "plugin:vue/vue3-essential", 
        "plugin:vue/vue3-strongly-recommended",
        "plugin:vue/vue3-recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": "latest",
        "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "plugins": [
        "vue",
        "@typescript-eslint"
    ],
    "rules": {
        "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": "error",
        "@typescript-eslint/no-inferrable-types": "error",
        "semi": "error"
    },
    "overrides": [
      {
        "files": ["*.vue"],
        "rules": {
          "no-undef": "off"
        }
      }
    ],
    "ignorePatterns": ["dist/**/*.js"],
    "root": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can say is that you have this:

```
"plugin:vue/vue3-essential", 
"plugin:vue/vue3-strongly-recommended",
"plugin:vue/vue3-recommended"
```

According to [eslint-plugin-vue](https://eslint.vuejs.org/user-guide/)  `vue3-strongly-recommended` includes `vue3-essential`. Also, `vue3-recommended` includes all. Which means that you might have duplicated the rules.

My advise is to use a ready eslint configuration like:

- [XO](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xo): General eslint rules (not specific to vue).
- [@antfu/eslint-config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@antfu/eslint-config): A sharable eslint config with vue, react and typescript support.
- [@kalimahapps/eslint-config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@kalimahapps/eslint-config): **(Disclaimer: I am the owner of this package)**. A sharable eslint config with vue and typescript support.